# PostgreSQL Wildcard and sub select count

Tags: postgresql

Having two tables , inventory and lots, i am using inventory table to save description of item including categories if items as well, filtered by the field inventory.type as inventory.type = ‘isInventoryItem’ or inventory.type = ‘Variety’ and inventory.invid as TEXT, and the lots table to hold the lots.

```
    invid     |  type   
 Sugraone     | Variety
 Autumn Royal | Variety
 Flame        | Variety
 Summer Royal | Variety
 Red Globe    | Variety
```

and for items it like this:

```
       invid                                |      type
  Sugraone 19#Pouch Free Bird Ctn B         | isInventoryItem
  Red Globe 21#PlainSO Chelan Starr 7L Sty  | isInventoryItem
  Flame 19#Pouch SO2 Puro Filete 5L Styro A | isInventoryItem
```

I would like to be able to select the type='Variety' from inventory and count the instances in the lots table by category using LIKE for the inventory.invid I have try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(inventory.*) AS lots, invid FROM lots
 INNER JOIN inventory ON lots.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
 WHERE invid ILIKE ANY (SELECT '%' || invid || '%' 
 from inventory WHERE type ='isInventoryItem') GROUP BY invid;
```

with not succeed, I would like this output:

```
    invid     |  count   
 Sugraone     | 5
 Autumn Royal | 6
 Flame        | 3
 Summer Royal | 7
 Red Globe    | 23
```

what would be the approach to do this.

EDIT: I added a view (items_view) only listing the invid AS name already filtered, getting only the list of items to search for category to make it simple:

```
                       name
```

---

```
Flame 19#Pouch Acosta Produce Ctn B
Flame 19#Pouch Acosta Produce Ctn B
Flame 19#Pouch SO2 J.A.P. Black 5L Styro B
Red Globe 21#PlainSO Chelan Starr 7L Sty
Red Globe 21#PlainSO Chelan Starr 7L Sty
Sugraone 19#Pouch Free Bird Ctn B
Summer Royal 19#Pouch SO2 SF White Od 5L Styro A
Summer Royal 19#Pouch Top Gun Cnt A
```

and I can get the list of categories like this: Select inid from inventory where type ='Variety' and I get the list as below:

```
    invid     
--------------
 Sugraone
 Autumn Royal
 Flame
 Summer Royal
 Red Globe
```

Now the question is how to loop through the list out this category list using LIKE for counting out on the list of inventory items and get the result as below

```
    invid     |  count   
 Sugraone     | 1
 Autumn Royal | 2
 Flame        | 3
 Summer Royal | 2
 Red Globe    | 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `invid` of rows with `type = 'isInventoryItem'` as a pattern. Instead, use the rows with `type = 'Variety'` as pattern:

```
SELECT  invid 
,       COUNT(inventory.*) AS lots
FROM    lots
INNER   inventory 
ON      lots.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
WHERE   inventory.type = 'isInventoryItem' 
        AND invid ILIKE ANY 
        (
        SELECT  '%' || invid || '%' 
        FROM    inventory 
        WHERE   type = 'Variety'
        ) 
GROUP BY
        invid
```

As a side note, consider studying [database design and normal forms](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/2014/SelfPaced/about).  You should probably have a separate table for categories of inventory, instead of including the categories in the inventory table itself.

Comment: You are absolutely right on having a category table, sadly the design is not mine

Comment: I edited the question for clarity, I thought that with your answer and some workaround I find the way that would satisfy the criteria, but still  I have not found a way